# Difference between bool and *bool

Tags: go, aws-sdk-go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/route53"
)

func main() {
    sess := session.Must(session.NewSession())
    client := route53.New(sess)
    zones, err := client.ListHostedZones(&route53.ListHostedZonesInput{
        MaxItems: aws.String("100"),
    })
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error occurred")
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v", zones)
    if zones.IsTruncated {
        fmt.Printf("%v", zones.NextMarker)
    }
}
```

The code above fails due to the following condition.

```
if zones.IsTruncated {
    fmt.Printf("%v", zones.NextMarker)
}
```

with the result of

```
non-bool zones.IsTruncated (type *bool) used as if condition
```

What I want to know is why is there a difference between a regular type(bool) and type(*bool).  I understand one is a pointer value however, the condition should still be useful.

Here is a tailed snippet of the output without the condition in place

```
IsTruncated: true,
MaxItems: "100",
NextMarker: "Wouldn'tYouLikeToKnow"
}
```

Comment: A pointer isn't a boolean.

Comment: @user2357112 I understand that, what I don't understand is how to check in boolean fashion if the pointer points to a boolean.  If *bool points to a `bool` that is `true` how would you check that in a condition.

Comment: Dereference the pointer.

Comment: user2357112  Thanks that was the solution.

Answer (score 8):

From [standard reference](https://golang.org/ref/spec#If_statements):

> "If" statements specify the conditional execution of two branches according to the value of a boolean expression.

So, to answer your question, `if` statements explicitly require boolean expressions. `*bool` is still not `bool`. You need to explicitly dereference the pointer (which could even be nil in which case your program will panic).

Here's how you would re-write your if statement:

```
if *zones.IsTruncated {
    fmt.Printf("%v", zones.NextMarker)
}
```

but make sure it is not nil

Answer (score 2):

You need to dereference to a struct. You need to use the := operator to do so. Something like -

```
new_struct := *your_pointer
```

You would then use the new_struct instead.